# NG2 : Pass attribute name to component using a variable

Tags: angular

I wish to pass data into a component but if possible I wish to store the name of the attribute inside a variable for example

```
<app-note-form-sticky [foreign_key_column]="foreign_key_value"></app-note-form-sticky>
```

Where "foreign_key_column" is a variable that holds the name of the attribute I wish to populate inside the component. Is it possible?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, with `[]` binding, the property name has to be statically added to the components template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare that as an Input inside your component (the one whose selector is app-note-form-sticky):

```
@Input() foreign_key_column: any;
```

**EDIT:** And this goes right before your constructor inside your class declaration for that component.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-note-form-sticky',
   template: 'your-template-link'
})
export class YourClass{
   @Input() foreign_key_column: any;
   constructor() {}
}
```